# How to obtain estimate of covariance matrix that will be guarantee to be semi-positive define?

Tags: probability, matrices, soft-question, parameter-estimation, estimation

How to obtain estimate of covariance matrix that will be guarantee to be semi-positive define ? (Is CrossValidated better place for this question ?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this www.quarchome.org/correlationmatrix.pdf

Comment: You should explain the information that you're linking to in your answer - if the link ever breaks, we don't want your answer to become useless. You can edit your answer to add more information.